# Font can't be imported in CSS

Tags: html, css, web, browser, frontend

I tried to import a lot of fonts that are free but non of them was successfully imported. I used: `Blox2.ttf`, `leaguegothic.woff`, `ADAM.CG PRO.otf`.

I tried this:

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'Blox';
    src: url(fonts/Blox2.ttf);
 }

.headerMain {
  font-family: 'Blox';
  font-size: 105px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 175px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

I opened console and saw this:

```
GET file:///C:/Users/Olga/Desktop/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD/fonts/Blox2.rtf 0 ()
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Blox2.rtf and Blox2.ttf. the filename extension is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in console's looking for *.rtf, when you're importing *.ttf font, look there, also you're sure that "fonts" folder is inside the same folder that .css file?

I'd also use '' in the url().